# Java - File save does not work

Tags: java, file, save, javafx-2

I would like to save an ArrayList's content to file (the user should choose the .txt's location) but I am not sure how to do that since that code does not work properly.

Do you have any idea how to do that?

```
package vizsgaquiz;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class VizsgaQuiz extends Application {

    ArrayList<String> kerdeslista = new ArrayList<String>();
    String a ="a";


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Foablak.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Quiz Játék");
        stage.show();
        save();
    }

    public void save(){
                kerdeslista.add(a);

                FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

              //Set extension filter
              FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TXT files (*.txt)", "*.txt");
              fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

              //Show save file dialog
              File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(stage);

              if(file != null){
                  SaveFile(kerdeslista, file);
              }
    }



    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Simplest: just give the `save(...)` method a Stage parameter and pass it in: `save(stage);` You already do this for the start method, so you should already know how to do this (which is why your question confuses me -- why not do what you've already done?).

Comment: Thank you! It is a good idea. Also could you tell me what is wrong with my save() method? It doesn't save the content of my ArrayList. Thank you!

Comment: I have no idea what the `SaveFile(...)` method is supposed to be doing. Is this your method? If so, where's the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues that may be causing this problem. For starters, this code wouldn't compile. This is because you call the variable *stage* in the method *save* which "died" in the method *start*. To call *stage* in *save*, you either need to pass it to *save* or save it as a field. The second issue is that the method *SaveFile* doesn't seem to exist. An example of *SaveFile* might look something like the code included below. Please note that I updated the method *save* to take in a Stage and I changed the name of the method *SaveFile* to *saveFile* to match Java naming conventions. Also, the code below prints each value of the arraylist on a new line, which you may not want.

```
    package vizsgaquiz;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;


    public class VizsgaQuiz extends Application {

      ArrayList<String> kerdeslista = new ArrayList<String>();
      String a ="a";


      @Override
      public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Foablak.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Quiz Játék");
        stage.show();
        save(stage);
      }

      public void save(Stage stage){
        kerdeslista.add(a);

        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

        //Set extension filter
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TXT files (*.txt)", "*.txt");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

        //Show save file dialog
        File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(stage);

        if(file != null){
          saveFile(kerdeslista, file);
        }
      }


      /**
       * @param args the command line arguments
       */
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
      }

      public static void saveFile(ArrayList<String> list, File file) {
        try {
          PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file);
          for (String val : list)
            out.println(val + "\n");
          out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how to save a new file to specified directory and name of file from FileDialog , Strings taken from a vector of Strings.It works for me !

```
 public static void SaveFileTo(Vector<String> myLines) {
            FileOutputStream f = null;
            DataOutputStream h = null;
            FileDialog d = new FileDialog(new JFrame(), "Save", FileDialog.SAVE);
            d.setVisible(true);
            String dir;
            dir = d.getDirectory();
            File oneFile = new File(dir + d.getFile());
            try {
                oneFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                f = new FileOutputStream(oneFile);
                h = new DataOutputStream(f);
                for (String de : myLines) {
                    h.writeBytes(de);               
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                try {
                    h.close();
                    f.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
```